# Create Divs for each part of an external JSON

Tags: html, jquery, json

So I've put together the basics to drawn down and display a peice of JSON which is hosted externally as follows:

JSON looks like this:

```
{
 "title": "National bullets",
 "source": "Dataloft",
 "data": {
"Economy": [
  "The UK economy remained static in February, the effects of strike action countering a rise in construction activity. In the three months to February the ONS report the economy grew by 0.1%",
  "At 10.1% in the year to March, the rate of inflation fell just 0.3% from February. Food prices continue to rise, while fuel prices have moderated.  Inflation is predicted to fall over the course of 2023. ",
  "The Bank of England has raised the base rate of interest to 4.25%, its highest rate in 14 years, with expectations the rate will peak at 4.5% this year. The MPC next meet on 11th May. "
],
"Transactions": [
  "The number of sales agreed in March 2023 was just 1% lower than in March 2019 according to Rightmove. This represents the first time the volume of sales agreed has been back to its pre-pandemic level since September 2022. ",
  "At +1 a net balance of agents expect sales growth in the next 12 months, the first time the RICS indicator has been positive since March 2022. Agents expect volumes to remain under pressure over the next three months. \r\n",
  "The HMRC report 90,340 transactions took place in February 2023, 18% lower than 2022 and 7% lower the last so-called 'normal' market of 2019.  "
],
"House prices": [
  "Price moderation of 6.8% is expected for the housing market over the course of 2023/24 according to the latest official forecasts by the Office of Budget Responsibility. Price growth of over 19% was recorded for 2021-22. ",
  "At 4.5% the discount on asking price to achieve a sale is the highest for 5 years (Zoopla), with many prospective sellers overly optimistic in their pricing in the current market. ",
  "The average house price in January stood at £288,074, down 1.1% from the previous month, but up 6.3% from the same time a year ago (UK HPI, ONS)."
],
"Demand": [
  "Buyer demand for property has risen considerably since December. According to Propertymark there were 94 prospective buyers registered per branch in February, compared to 70 in January and 39 in December. ",
  "At 43,536 mortgage approvals in February were 34% lower than the pre-pandemic  (2015-2019) average but were 10% higher than January. Pre-pandemic approvals in February were usually slightly lower than in January. ",
  "40% of respondents to the latest RICS Residential Market Survey state they are seeing more interest from buyers in homes that are more energy efficient, with 61% of respondents stating energy efficient homes were holding their value in current market conditions. "
],
"Development": [
  "The government is proposing that all homes sold will need to have an Energy Performance Certificate rating of C by 2033, with no new homes to be built with a gas boiler from 2025. The proposals form part of the Governments 'Net Zero Review'.",
  "Despite an overall rise in construction activity in March, activity in the housing sector decreased, with respondents noting fewer tendering opportunities due to rising costs (IHS Markit).",
  "Over 260,000 new homes were built in 2022, up 3.3% on 2022. Over 68,000 new homes were completed in the final quarter, up 8.9% year-on-year according to data released by the DLUHC."
],
"Investment/lettings": [
  "Demand for rental properties is at a five month high according to the latest survey by RICS. Demand continues to outpace supply with pressure on rental values continuing. \r\n\r\n",
  "Annual growth in private rental prices in the UK rose to 4.9% in the year to March, many regions of England and Wales experiencing the strongest growth since records began.The ONS Index of Private Housing Rental Prices includes pre-existing and new lets. ",
  "The government is consulting on plans that would require homeowners to obtain planning permission before converting properties into short-term holiday lets in tourist locations. It is likely a rental period of between 30-90 days would be allowed before permission is required. \r\n\r\n"
],
"Prime markets": [
  "The introduction of a Register of Overseas Entities has led to a significant reduction in property deals in the UK  involving offshore tax havens compared to other overseas localities according to research by the Brookings Institution.",
  "There has been a sharp drop in supply in the prime London rental market. Lettings instructions were 21% lower in the second fortnight of the year compared to the first, and down 12% in the following two-week period (Knight Frank).\r\n",
  "There were 21% fewer sales recorded in PCL in Q1 this year than Q1 2022, and a 22% drop from the previous quarter. However, more sales were recorded in Q1 2023 than any first quarter between 2017 and 2020 (JLL)."
]
}
}
```

The script I've got for drawing down the JSON data and inserting it into the HTML is as follows:

```
    let dataloft_national_bullets_url = "https://inform.dataloft.co.uk/api/BAh7CEkiCGdpZAY6BkVUSSIrZ2lkOi8vaW5mb3JtL1VzZXJBcmVhLzI2NzM2P2V4cGlyZXNfaW4GOwBUSSIMcHVycG9zZQY7AFRJIgxkZWZhdWx0BjsAVEkiD2V4cGlyZXNfYXQGOwBUMA==--36ebf74c32194c59ad4a7d9fb89db230a66efadf/V8UDrS9mIAVkNJcgBI3e3Q/national_bullets"



    fetch(dataloft_national_bullets_url)

        .then((response) => response.json())

        .then((payload) => {

            let container = document.getElementById("national_bullets_target_container")

            for (const div in payload.data) {

                let data = document.createElement('div')

                data.appendChild(document.createTextNode(div))

                container.appendChild(data)


                for (const chapter in payload.data) {

                    let header = document.createElement('h1')

                    header.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chapter))

                    container.appendChild(header)



                    for (const paragraph in payload.data[chapter]) {

                        let para = document.createElement('li')

                        para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(payload.data[chapter][paragraph]))

                        container.appendChild(para)

                    }

                }
            }
        })

</script>
```

My html is as simple as:

```
   <div id="national_bullets_target_container"></div>
```

I'm trying now to fetch each array as a div. As I want to put the JSON data into a slider.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: Because the JSON is quite long, I would recommend visiting the URL: https://inform.dataloft.co.uk/api/BAh7CEkiCGdpZAY6BkVUSSIrZ2lkOi8vaW5mb3JtL1VzZXJBcmVhLzI2NzM2P2V4cGlyZXNfaW4GOwBUSSIMcHVycG9zZQY7AFRJIgxkZWZhdWx0BjsAVEkiD2V4cGlyZXNfYXQGOwBUMA==--36ebf74c32194c59ad4a7d9fb89db230a66efadf/V8UDrS9mIAVkNJcgBI3e3Q/national_bullets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the additional loop: `for (const div in payload.data)`?

```js
let dataloft_national_bullets_url =
  'https://inform.dataloft.co.uk/api/BAh7CEkiCGdpZAY6BkVUSSIrZ2lkOi8vaW5mb3JtL1VzZXJBcmVhLzI2NzM2P2V4cGlyZXNfaW4GOwBUSSIMcHVycG9zZQY7AFRJIgxkZWZhdWx0BjsAVEkiD2V4cGlyZXNfYXQGOwBUMA==--36ebf74c32194c59ad4a7d9fb89db230a66efadf/V8UDrS9mIAVkNJcgBI3e3Q/national_bullets';

fetch(dataloft_national_bullets_url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((payload) => {
    let container = document.getElementById(
      'national_bullets_target_container'
    );

    for (const chapter in payload.data) {
      const data = document.createElement('div');
      data.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chapter));

      let header = document.createElement('h1');
      header.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chapter));
      data.appendChild(header);

      for (const paragraph in payload.data[chapter]) {
        let para = document.createElement('li');
        para.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(payload.data[chapter][paragraph])
        );
        data.appendChild(para);
      }

      container.appendChild(data);
    }
  });
```

```html
<div id="national_bullets_target_container"></div>
```